# How can I show each questions with for loop?

Tags: loops, for-loop, button

i want to see next question when i click yes or no button. 
Firsth question is ready on main_activity.xml, but to see second question users should answer with yes or no button. How can i do this?

```
    final TextView questionsText;
    Button buttonYes;
    Button buttonNo;

    String questions[] = new String[7];
    questions[0] = "Second question about depression";
    questions[1] = "Third question about depression";
    questions[2] = "Fourth question about depression";

    questionsText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text1);
    buttonYes = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonYes);
    buttonNo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonNo);

    buttonYes.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
                questionsText.setText(i);
            }
        }
    });

    buttonNo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
                questionsText.setText(i);
            }
        }
    });
} }
```